# How to find rows that share the same combination index?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, indexing

I have a combination index of 3 columns. I want to find the rows that have the same value for this index.  This is my index:

```
CREATE INDEX foobar ON tablename (foo, bar, asdf);
```

The index is not unique. I created it with the idea that it would help me find rows that share the same values in these 3 columns (foo, bar, asdf).

Alternatively, I could create a new column whose value is the combination of the 3 other column values. But is that my only choice?

Can I use this index for what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Index aren't used to group data, but locate it within a table.

If you wish to find items which share common values, you would do better to run a query such as

```
  SELECT foo, bar, asdf, SUM(1) as counter 
    FROM mytable 
GROUP BY foo, bar, asdf
```

This will show you items with multiples, you could do a longer fancier query to extrapolate the ones with a counter > 1 and then fetch the values for it:

```
  SELECT t.foo, t.bar, t.asdf, SUM(1) as counter 
    FROM mytable AS t
GROUP BY t.foo, t.bar, t.asdf 
  HAVING counter > 1;
```

Comment: So the first select gets you items with multiples (irrespective to how many multiples exist?)...

Comment: The first query will list how many rows have each unique (foo, bar, asdf) triplet.  So e.g. a result of `4|34|x|3` would indicate that 3 rows exist with foo = 4, bar = 34, and asdf = 'x' but would not tell you anything else about those rows.  You will see results for every triplet in your data, even those with only one matching row.

Answer (score 0):

Your index will speed up queries where you want all the rows with particular values for those three columns, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE foo = 1 AND bar = 2 AND asdf = 3
```

I'm not sure, but it may also help with queries that sort the results such that matching rows are adjacent, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE somecondition ORDER BY foo, bar, asdf;
```

Based on your comment, it looks like you want something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') as ids, foo, bar, asdf, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM tablename GROUP BY foo, bar, asdf HAVING cnt > 1;
```

That will tell you which rows are duplicates, and you can go from there to check whatever you need for individual sets.  If you want to do everything with one query, you may be able to use some heavier SQL to do it, but it won't be simple.

Comment: I want to find rows that have the same values for those 3 columns. (These rows are duplicate widgets, so to speak, but they do have differences in other columns.) I then want to perform calculations on these rows as separate groups. For example, I want to sum a certain column of these rows or find out which row has longest string in another column (not one of the 3 columns), etc